Trying to use '' npm install" on company system. and now i amd getting this error
[i just copy this commanrt from npm after publish this pakage and it give me this error i want to fix this isue as soon as possible it will be glad iff anyone help me.i can see many people ans about it but it cant help in my situation and now i want to fix it  ]
(https://i.sstatic.net/0IRAXtCY.png)
i want to fix it so that i can see reflection on burpsuite collaborator
